# Copying Column A to Column B and Re-Ordering Column A

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `ph3`.`member` SET `name` =  (select Sname from member  order by rand())
```

I want to copy `Sname` to `name` and I want to re-order column `Sname`

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not supposed to be able to do an update to a table that is based on a select from the same table (ie: member).

As for re-ordering the column name, you don't need to physically change the records as you can 
just use an index on the name, in addition to using an ORDER BY clause during any of your queries.

Finally, if you DO based on your update command of random(), there is a STRONG possibility that some of the names will be more than duplicated, and others would be completely lost...  The update performs one record at a time. So, if you have names like "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" and "F"...

And your random() returns "E" first, then record 1 becomes "E" and "A" is now gone, then B gets processed and is randomed with "D", now "B" is gone and becomes "D"... time for C and it gets random D (ex: original B position) and now another "D", etc...

If you are trying to create a randomized jumble of names, I would suggest copying the results out to a test table ordering by random, then joining based on the same ID number as newly created to the original ID before it started.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass multiple values to a single set field of an update statement, if you want your query to work you have to limit the result to only one record, so :

```
UPDATE `ph3`.`member` SET `name` =  (select Sname from member  order by rand() LIMIT 1);
```

This query update the name field with a random name retrieved from the member table.

Comment: 1093 - You can't specify target table 'member' for update in FROM clause

Comment: UPDATE `ph3`.`member` SET `name` =  (select Sname order by rand() LIMIT 1)

Comment: ok, the table is the same, i didn't noticed ...